# line breaks in struts2 textarea

Tags: struts2

Is there way to add line breaks to `<s:textarea>` value?

```
<s:textarea name="text_area" value="need_some_line_breaks" />
```

thanks.

Comment: you can do that by `need_some_line_breaks.replace((\"\n\", \" <br />\")")`. I believe you are fetching the value from your action

Comment: yes.i fetch.but i need to add some line breaks **inside the value tag** before showing the value.

Comment: you can send HTML data from the action class with newline character and can replace them with <br> as shown by me in first comment.

Comment: thanks.is it the only way to do this?

Comment: well S2 tag do not provide this feature,though some tag provides `escapeHTMl` attribute but again for newline you have to do it by this way

Answer (score 1):

This isn't Struts 2-related at all, rather it's basic HTML.

If you want newlines inside a `<textarea>` put a newline (`"\n"`) in the string wherever you want one. Personally, I leave textarea data untouched and transform it only when I need to view it *outside* a text area, by replacing the newlines with `<br/>` tags. This way the original data is always preserved.

Comment: doing `<s:textarea cssClass="form-control" value="\n   abcd\n   " />` does not put newlines on the page for me...it literally shows up as `\n   abcd\n   `

Comment: @ZackMacomber I don't recall how it handles immediate string values; could be.